# Accessing Database: process per user, thread per user and shared pool

Tags: database, multithreading, parallel-processing

During the webinar I heard that there are three ways to access a database for a number of users:

1. Using process per user
2. Thread per user
3. And pool of processes

The lecturer said that process per user avoid the need to take care of parallelization/locking/etc but is too heavy and complex. Thread per user is lightweight, but requires a lot of locking overhead. Pool of processes have shared data structure when accessing DB.

What is not clear to me is - arent users always access the same datastructure and regardless whether we have process or thread or poll - we still need to implement locking? Why would processes not require locking? What is the diff between process per user and pool of processes? As lecturer said - shared data structures. But what does it mean if processes dont share DB? Is DB replicated for each user assuming we are in process per user situation?

I really want this to get clarified, but I could not ask this during the webinar.

Thank you!

Comment: The database server is going to have to implement some sort of locking scheme to support multiple simultaneous connections, yes. I suspect that what you heard was talk about client-side synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Locking is required only if you have some shared resource. When connecting to DB you first create a connection object and then through that object you connect and send your queries. In `MySQL innoDb` the database performs row level locking and not the entire table is locked. So if multiple process are trying to access different rows no locking will be required.

Coming to Threads, what people mostly do is they create a connection pool where multiple `threads` access that pool. Let say you have 50 threads and connection pool of 5 objects. Now all 50 thread cannot access these 5 connection objects they need to wait for the connection object to be free and once it is free they can use the connection object to fire query . Threads share same memory space so mostly all shared resources must be thread safe

Since creation of a process is quite heavy, you would want to keep it less max 10-20 processes on 4gb machine. But threads are less costly to create you can have them in large numbers (~50). So if there nothing to be shared Threads will give more parallelism.

Again everything boils down to how good is your design and that is very problem specific.